# WSO2 BPS creating a BPEL human task throws 411 Error: Length Required

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

Having a BPEL process creating a human task, creating a RemoteTask throws the  following exception (note that the BPEL process runs ok until the human task and I can create the human task invoking its WS endpoint)) :

```
Error sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex 
{PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphrbsqc3x2nneo [PID {http://b2bg2.imtech.realdolmen.com/bps/sample}HumanTaskTest-17] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@4e72a575.ErrorHandling(...) Status REQUEST}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:331)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:196)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
            at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.utils.AxisServiceUtils.invokeService(AxisServiceUtils.java:316)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService.invoke(PartnerService.java:324)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.invokePartner(BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.java:43)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.invoke(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:897)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.INVOKE.run(INVOKE.java:130)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:451)
            at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU.execute(JacobVPU.java:139)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.execute(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:1002)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.invokeNewInstance(PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.java:208)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$1.invoke(BpelProcess.java:283)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:224)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:279)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails(BpelProcess.java:434)
            at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.onScheduledJob

(BpelEngineImpl.java:558)
        at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelServerImpl.java:467)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:633)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:298)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:253)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
        at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:611)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For me it looks like the Content-Length header neither the "chunked"  is not present when the web services are called internally between the BPEL process and the HT implemention

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the WSDL of the HT (human task) must have the valid service endpoint address in the service declaration. The default WSDL created by Eclipse (WSO2 DEV) has the endpoint set to the www.example.org.

I assumed the internal transport is used (as it is between processes), but apparently it's not true :(